# Error during installation of feature in Karaf (MultiException & ZipException)

Tags: osgi, talend, karaf

I get a strange error while I am trying to install (any) 3rd party library in Karaf (4.0.5). I use Oracle JDK 1.8.0_102 in centos7. 
My features.xml looks as below.

```
<features>
<feature name="feature1" version="1.0.0">
    <bundle>wrap:file://home/talend/Documents/SampleRoute/Text-maker.jar</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

To add the features.xml I used the following command.
karaf@trun()># feature:repo-add file:///opt/talend/trun/etc/features.xml

To install feature1, I executed the following command,
karaf@trun()># feature:install feature1

But I get following exception:

*2016-08-27 02:40:35,445 | ERROR | nsole user karaf | ShellUtil                        | 52 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.0.5 | Exception caught while executing command
**org.apache.karaf.features.internal.util.MultiException**: Error
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.(MavenDownloadManager.java:84)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:72)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:363)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:360)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.5]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_102]
**Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 1759510536 but got 190 bytes)**
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384)[:1.8.0_102]*

Comment: Seems to me that the jar file is too small.

Comment: I wish it was. But not so. Its of 42KB